# In how many ways can $1,2$, and $5$ dollar bills be used total up to $19$ dollars?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Is there any easy method to do it? Worth noting is that here the answer sets like $\left\{5,5,5,1,2,1\right\}$ and $\left\{5,5,5,2,1,1\right\}$ will be counted separately.

Please don't mark it as a duplicate because I do not know programming/or advanced mathematics but I need to know the answer.

Comment: Why do you "need" to know the answer?

Answer (score 6):

Let $a_n$ mean the number of ways you can make $n$ dollars. Then $a_0=1$, $a_k=0$ for every $k<0$, and
$$ a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-5} $$
for all $n\ne 0$.

Write down a table of the $a_n$s starting with $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ and using your previous results in each step. After $19$ three-element additions you will have your answer!

---

(For large values of $19$ there are clever ways to speed this calculation up, but I don't think they are worth it in this small case).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this works?

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk: Until the OP reveals what his interest in the problem is, I prefer to let him do some of the thinking himself.

Comment: And this, sir, is why your rep is an order of magnitude above mine. O_o

Comment: OK I *finally* figured out why this works. Man, that's clever! :)

Comment: @John: Oh, sorry, I didn't grasp you had problems with that. I thought your first comment was an "obvious once you see it" one.

Comment: Haha no problem! Yeah, you (a) arrived at the answer more quickly, (b) it was easier than mine, and (c) I didn't see why it worked initially! More the flavor of my comment was: "I'm completely outgunned on this one." :)

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it this seems like a tedious problem.

First I'd enumerate all of the $26$ possible combinations of bills. (There are three combinations that use three $5$s, five that use two, eight that use one, and ten that use nothing but $2$s and $1$s.)

Then I'd separately calculate the number of permutations for each combination (with multinomials), and add them all up.

There may be an easier answer but I'm not seeing it ...